# get emoji name from <:Emoji_name:ID>

Tags: javascript, discord.js, emoji

Alright so i'm trying to get the name of the emoji from this <:Emoji_name:ID>. But .slice() doesnt work and i've kinda reached the end of my knowledge here, So uh yeah if anyone could help that be nice! Heres my command code.

```js
else if (command === 'emoji') {
  let findEmoji = msg.content.match(/<a:.+?:\d+>|<:.+?:\d+>/g)
  if (!findEmoji) return msg.reply("Please mention an emoji!")
  oneEmoji = findEmoji.slice(0, 1)
  emojiId = msg.content.match(/\d+/g)
  oneEmojiId = emojiId.slice(0, 1)
  embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Emoji information")
    .addFields({
      name: 'Emoji name:',
      value: "coming soon",
      inline: true
    }, {
      name: 'Emoji for bots:',
      value: "`" + oneEmoji + "`",
      inline: true
    }, {
      name: 'Emoji id:',
      value: oneEmojiId,
      inline: true
    }, {
      name: 'Emoji link:',
      value: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/${oneEmojiId}.png?v=1`,
      inline: true
    }, )
    .setThumbnail(`https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/${oneEmojiId}.png?v=1`)
  msg.channel.send(embed)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let args = msg.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/); //be sure to specify the prefix or just get rid of that part
let namever1 = args[1].replace('<','')
let namever2 = namever1.replace('>','')
let namever3 = namever2.split(':')
let name = namever3[1] //Emoji name
let id = namever3[2] //emoji id
//if you want the link: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/"+id+".png?/v=1"
//also note theres a difference between animated and none animated (aniamted ones require "let namever1 = ForBots.replace('<a','')" also the link has to change to "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/"+id+".gif?/v=1")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
let args = message.content.split(" ");
let command = args[0].slice(1).toLowerCase();
/*
Let's guess you have some if .... else
*/
else if (command === "emoji"){
    if(args[1].match(/<a:.+?:\d+>|<:.+?:\d+>/g)){  //The OP's regex
        let emoji;
        if(args[1] === "a"){
            emoji = args[1].slice(3, (args[1].length-1) ); //animated
        }else{
            emoji = args[1].slice(2, (args[1].length-1) ); //Non animated
        }
        emojiID = emoji.split(":")[1];
        emojiName = emoji.split(":")[0];
        // Put the embed
    }
}
```

I know this is a bad piece of code. But it works

Comment: I'm getting cringed seeing my own code. If you can make it better please feel free to edit

Comment: yeah that didnt work it just removes the whole name instead of the : ty for trying tho lol